# how to combine list of tuples based on common value into a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a long list of tuples, could look like this for example:

```
[('5','9'), ('10','11'), ('1','2'), ('1','3'), ('1','4'), ('2','7'), ('3','8'), ('2','1'), ('3','1'), ('3','4'), ('5','6'),  ('5','10'),  ('10','12'), ('11','13'), ('13','14')]
```

I need to combine them into lists if they share anything in common. So the output in the example would be:

```
['11', '10', '13', '12', '14', '5', '6', '9']
['1', '3', '2', '4', '7', '8']
```

**To clarify:** the input is a list of tuples. I need to combine all tuples with shared element into one list. So if I will have: [('1','2'), ('1','3'), ('1','4'), ('4','5')], all the elements should all be put into one list ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], because they are linked through the tuples.

I tried to come up with something going through dictionaries byt failed miserably. I am sure there some "easier" solution.

thank you
Martin

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I should add I am working in python

Comment: I've added the python tag. If you don't add a language tag hardly anyone sees your question.

Comment: Can you clarify what _share anything in common_ means?

Comment: @PaulBoddington: So the input is a list of tuples. I need to combine all tuples with shared element into one list. So if I will have: [('1','2'), ('1','3'), ('1','4'), ('4','5')], all the elements should all be put into one list ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], because they are linked through the tuples.

Comment: @woozyking I worked it out. Basically you want as many groups as possible, but if `(a, b)` is one of the original tuples, `a` and `b` must be in the same group.

Comment: Good to know. You can post your own answer to help others who may have similar questions in the future.

Comment: @mkol That makes more sense. I'd put that information in the question, because it's quite difficult to spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are doing union-find operations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Start with creating singleton disjoint sets, each having a number occurring in your list. Next, for each tuple, union the sets corresponding to the numbers in the tuple.

The above solution will have running time nearly linear in the number of tuples. See [A set union find algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3067529/567555) for possible union-find implementations.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Find a code in the link you posted that worked!

Answer (score 0):

We can frame this problem as that of finding connected components in an undirected graph. All distinct numbers that appear in the list can be treated as the nodes (vertices) of the graph, and the pairs as its edges.

Here is a simple algorithm with inline comments:

```
l = [('5','9'), ('10','11'), ('1','2'), ('1','3'), ('1','4'), ('2','7'), ('3','8'), ('2','1'), ('3','1'), ('3','4'), ('5','6'),  ('5','10'),  ('10','12'), ('11','13'), ('13','14')]

# get all unique elements ("nodes") of `l'
nodes = set().union(*map(set, l))

# start with each node in its own connected component
comp = {node:{node} for node in nodes}

# now repeatedly merge pairs of components connected by edges in `l'
while True:
  merged = False
  new_l = []  # will drop edges that have already been used in a merge
  for n1, n2 in l:
    if comp[n1] is not comp[n2]:
      # the two connected components are not the same, so merge them
      new_comp = comp[n1] | comp[n2]
      for n in new_comp:
        comp[n] = new_comp
      merged = True
    else:
      # keep the pair for the next iteration
      new_l.append((n1, n2))
  if not merged:
    # all done
    break
  l = new_l

# now print all distinct connected components
for c in set(map(frozenset, comp.values())):
  print list(c)
```

This prints out:

```
['1', '3', '2', '4', '7', '8']
['11', '10', '13', '12', '14', '5', '6', '9']
```